# $(...).datepicker is not a function- works on one server but not on another

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know this topic was opened here a lot, and I know that the problem for other users was that they included the Jquery.js file more than one time so there was a conflict between the files, however this isn't my case but I am still getting this error and couldn't find a solution that worked for me from previous Questions.

This is the code I am using on the .aspx file head section

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href = "css/jquery-ui.min.css"rel = "stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/UserPlans.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I made sure that the jquery link comes before the jquery-ui

and in UserPlans.js file I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#calendar").click(function () {

      $('#datepicker').datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date($("#formatedDate").val()) });
  });

  $('#datepicker').datepicker();

});
```

I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (UserPlans.js?v=57153.032911662754:8)
at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

However, I must point out that this code is in production in two different servers, in one of them it works without any problems, and in the other it gives this error I have just described. can it be related to the hosting machine somehow?

Comment: Just because you have a reference to `jquery-ui.js` does not necessarily mean that it is available. it can be missing if the js file was custom created with the [download builder](https://jqueryui.com/download/). Second, to be safe use `src= "/js/jquery-ui.js"` (assuming the js folder is in the root of the site).

Comment: I edited my post, It works on one machine and not on another one. when checking with developer tools I see the file was downloaded.